# When exactly is a destructor or terminate on a thread called

Tags: c++11, stdthread

I am using C++11 std::thread. My confusion is based on the following:

`terminate()` on a thread is called if neither `join()` nor `detach()` is called on it.
That means when a thread returns:

**a.** it checks whether a `join()` or `detach()` on it is called, if not, then `terminate()` is called(produces a coredump),

**b.** if `join()` is called the destructor of the thread would be called by main(or calling thread)

**c.** if a `detach()` *was* called while the thread was executing, the thread won't return to main for cleanup, instead this thread itself will be responsible for calling its own destructor

**Question:** If the above points were true then i dont understand ***at which exact point*** is the decision made wehter to terminate a thread or not based on whether a `join()` or `detach()` is called or not?

```
void function_1()
{
        return;
}
int main()
{
        std::thread t1(function_1);
        std::cout<<"\nFirst Sleep for 5 seconds:\n"; 
        sleep(5);

        cout<<"\n2nd Sleep for 5 seconds:\n";
        sleep(5);

        if(t1.joinable())
        {
                cout<<"\nGonna join()\n";
                t1.detach();
        }
        cout<<"Exiting from main ...\n";
```

}

Since the thread would finish its execution before 5th second, i assumed the thread should be terminated as there is no `join()/detach()` till this point. But there's no `terminate()` called. Instead a thread is detached succesfully.

However if i dont detach then terminate is called after 2 sleep after `"Exiting from main...."`, right before `return 0;`
Does that mean that the thread is not cleaned up(its destructor not called), until main thread(or called thread) returns?

Is that the reason why one should `detach()` so that the cleanup of the thread doesn't have to wait till main(or caller thread) returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing two things: the `std::thread` object, and the thread of execution that that object manages.

The call to `std::terminate` is triggered by the destructor of the `std::thread` object *if* it is joinable. This is not directly related to whether or not the thread of execution managed by the `std::thread` object has finished executing.

In your code, the destructor of `t1` is what would trigger `std::terminate`. `t1` is an ordinary C++ object, a local variable of `main` here. It gets destructed when its scope ends - end of main here. So you must have made `t1` non-joinable before main returns, either by calling `join` or `detach` on `t1`. Whether `function_1` has finished running on its thread of execution or not is not relevant.